# WCF Service Host - Serviço não registra porta se não executar VS como Administrador

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-service

Olá, ao tentar executar um WebService do tipo ServiceLibrary. O WCF Service Host me dá a seguinte má notícia :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Please try changing the HTTP port to 8733 or running as Administrator.
>   System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not
>   register URL http://+:8733/. Your process does not have access rights
>   to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353
>   for details). ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Acesso negado

Se eu iniciar o Visual Studio como Administrador, consigo executar o serviço.

Mas tem como resolver isso, sem executar o Visual Studio como administrador?

Comment: Já tentou da permissão de administrador para a aplicação?

Comment: Não. Como faço isso?

Comment: Da uma olhada [aqui](http://chrsmrtn.azurewebsites.net/wcf-service-library-admin-required/).